# Send a IMAGE on Discord was Bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

whatsup?!

I'm starting a new research on java and i'm cracking my head about how to send image when i set the command in client side.

> if(result == 1 ) {
> message.channel.send('4 ★ Great Staff', {
> files: [
> "./test.jpeg"
> ]
> }); }

What give me on server side

> ReferenceError: message is not defined
> at Object.pull (C:\Bot\neobot\gacha.js:12:15)
> at Client. (C:\Bot\neobot\index.js:17:39)
> at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Bot\neobot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
> at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Bot\neobot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:100:65)
> at WebSocketManager.eventMessage (C:\Bot\neobot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:225:31)
> at WebSocket.ws.onmessage (C:\Bot\neobot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:83:37)
> at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Bot\neobot\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:442:14)
> at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at Receiver.ontext (C:\Bot\neobot\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:841:10)

Comment: Read the error, message isn't defined. Please include more code.

Comment: We'll need to see some more code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MessageAttachment` which comes with discord.js

`const { MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js")`

`const image = new MessageAttachment(LINK HERE)`
And you can do more customizations

For more info:
https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/docs/examples/attachments.md